# Apache 2.4.37 mod_deflate not works

Tags: server, 18.04, apache2, apache2.4

I've installed Apache 2.4.37 via `ppa:ondrej/apache2` and can't make `mod_deflate` (gzip compression) works. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 server.

mod_deflate is enabled in Apache:

```
sudo apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES | grep deflate
deflate_module (shared)
```

I placed code into `.htaccess`:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA,NE]
```

`.htaccess` is enabled by Apache config (and redirection works).

When I try: `curl -I -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' http://myserver/pokus.css`

is returned:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Thu, 24 Jan 2019 12:20:00 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.37 (Ubuntu)
Location: https://myserver/pokus.css
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

So file is returned uncompressed.

I also tried to add deflate command directly into VirtualHost, but without success.

No error message in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. Apache is restarted also without errors.

Any idea?

Comment: Hello, Jan Hana, did you find answer of your question?

Answer (score 1):

The webserver sends mime-type `text/html`, while you filter by mime-type `text/css`.

This does obviously not work. Either filter by `text/html` (which will include all html), update the mime type for CSS, or use `AddOutputFilter` for css file extension:

```
AddOutputFilter css
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the response `Content-Type: text/html;` unnecessary disappointing you. But first, let's check the configuration.

1. `mod_deflate` depends on `mod_filter` so the booth should be enabled and the server should be restarted then.
2. In the file `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/deflate.conf` you can see, when the above requirements are satisfied, `mod_deflate` is enabled with some basic settings, so we do not need to do anything else to perform a test.

Actually you are looking for a response that contains some as the follow lines:

```bsh
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/css
```

The problem is when there is a response header with redirection `HTTP 301`/`HTTP 302` (as it is in your case) the received information is not complete. So **try to `curl` URL that will return header with `HTTP 200`**, or apply different method to do the test.

---

Let's assume on the server side we have the following `24K` large file:

```bsh
$ ls -l /var/www/html/test.css 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 24K Jan 24 22:10 /var/www/html/test.css
```

On the client side we can use `wget` in the following way to test whether the gzip compression works:

```bsh
wget --header="Accept-Encoding: gzip" http://example.com/test.css
```

If everything went fine the downloaded file `test.css` should be about `3K` large:

```bsh
$ wget --header="Accept-Encoding: gzip" gzip" http://example.com/test.css
...
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3045 (3.0K) [text/css]
Saving to: ‘test.css’

test.css   100%[===============================>]   2.97K  --.-KB/s    in 0s
```

You can check the content the downloaded file, it should be a different, compressed version of the original file.

---

References:

- [How To Install And Configure mod_deflate On Ubuntu - on DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-mod_deflate-on-ubuntu-14-04)